# Changing the highlighted color of textfield text on the custom cell of a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview with custom cells. The custom cells have textfields on them.

When a cell is highlighted, I would like to change the color of the text of the textfields from white to black.

I know about cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor, but can anyone think of a way to change it for a textfield?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the delegate protocol method *(available from iOS 6.0)* **tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:** or **tableView:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:** , depending on your requirements, to intercept the users touch and from there obtain a pointer to the **UITextField** of interest.

The following assumes to be inside an object that is both the table views **delegate** and **datasource**.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     // get the cell by calling datasource protocol method
     UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     // fast enumeration to get UITextField(s) from the cell
     for (UITextField *textField in cell.subviews) {
          // change color here...
          textField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
          }
     return YES;
}
```